# Multiple date diff//C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

How to calculate a multiple date difference like

```
startDate1=("dd-MM-yy") 20-08-2011 
endDate1=25-08-11
```

another

```
startdate2=27-08-2011 
endDate2=30-08-2011
```

such that output will be

```
(endDate1-startDate1)+(endDate2-StartDate2) == 8days //only in terms of days
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete Code/Answer....

```
public class DateController : Controller
{

  public ActionResult date()
    {
        int allDiff;
        List<int> list=new List<int>();
        int flag = 0;
        int conflict = 0;
        List<int> conf = new List<int>();
        conf.Add(0);
        int a = 0;

        DateTime[] startDate = new DateTime[3];
        startDate[0] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 5);
        startDate[1] = new DateTime(2011, 11,7);
        startDate[2] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 15);

        DateTime[] endDate = new DateTime[3];
        endDate[0] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 10);
        endDate[1] = new DateTime(2011, 11,12);
        endDate[2] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 20);


        DateTime Min= startDate.Min();
        DateTime Max = endDate.Max();

        TimeSpan span = Max - Min;
        int total = span.Days;
        ViewBag.globalTotal = total;


        foreach (DateTime e in endDate)
        {

            foreach (DateTime s in startDate)
            {
                if (s >= e)
                {
                    TimeSpan span1 = s - e;
                    allDiff = span1.Days;                    
                    list.Add(allDiff);
                    flag = 1;
                    conflict = 1;
                }
                else {
                    flag = 0;
                }

            }
            if((list.Count==1)&&(conflict==1)&&(list!=null)){
                 a = list[0];
                conf.Add(a);
            }


            if ((flag == 1)&&(list.Count>1))
            {
                int m = list.Min();
                ViewBag.dhiraj = m;
                total = total - m;
                list.Clear();
            }

        }
        int confl= conf.Min();
        total=total-confl;
        ViewBag.Total = total;

        return View();
    }

}
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Use `TimeSpan` to calculate date difference.
Eg:

```
TimeSpan ts = Date1 - Date2; 
int numberOfDays = ts.Days;
```

More info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Date - or + Date will return TimeSpan, it has a property named "Days" is what you need.

```
((endDate1-startDate)+(endDate2-StartDate2)).Days
```

Comment: what if dates overlapped ie. s1=1 e1=10 s2=5 e2=11 needed output==11

Comment: TimeSpan actually is the number of miliseconds, duration of time. It won't be overlapped, the result could be positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
            DateTime d1 = StarDate
            DateTime d2 = EndDate;
            TimeSpan t1 = d2.Subtract(d1);
            days = t1.Days;
            hours = t1.Hours;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

> ```
>         DateTime strdate = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2011");
>         DateTime enddate = Convert.ToDateTime("1/10/2011");
>
>         DateTime strdate1 = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2011");
>         DateTime enddate1 = Convert.ToDateTime("1/10/2011");
>
>         int resultdays = (enddate.Subtract(strdate) + enddate1.Subtract(strdate1)).Days;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exact DateDiff function as it works in SQL, you can remove time stamp of the Date variables and then Subtract one from another. It will give u exact number of days. 
Ex.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(fromDate.ToShortDateString()); 
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(toDate.ToShortDateString()); 
int noOfDays = dt.Subtract(dt1).TotalDays;
```